# Waiting for code to complete in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, express

I have this code

```
var dataToSend2;

// spawn new child process to call the python script
const ls = spawn("python", ["./readDirectory.py"]);

// collect data from script
ls.stdout.on("data", function (info) {
  console.log("Pipe data from python script ...");
  dataToSend2 = JSON.parse(info);
  console.log(dataToSend2);
});

// in close event we are sure that stream from child process is closed
ls.on("close", (code) => {
  console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);

  // send data to browser
  for (i = 0; i < dataToSend2.length; i++) {
    console.log(dataToSend2[i]);
  }
});
```

Which runs this code on page load

```
import os
import json

items = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=True):
    items.append({'root': root, 'label': dirs, 'files': files})
print(json.dumps(items))
```

When I load the page, I get the error

```
{
    root: '.\\node_modules\\binary-extensions',
    label: [],
    files: [
      'binary-extensions.json',
      'binary-extensions.json.d.ts',
      'index.d.ts',
      'index.js',
      'license',
      'package.json',
      'readme.md'
    ]
  },
  ... 886 more items
]
Pipe data from python script ...
undefined:2



SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

I'm guessing this is due to it parsing the variable info before it has completed. Is there a way to set up an event timer to wait until it has finished running readDirectory.py and obtained the entire output before trying to parse the information? Or, maybe I have this all wrong and its a different problem?

Comment: Is there any reason you're leaning on Python when Node can easily handle this internally?

Answer (score 0):

A `data` event in a stream such as `ls.stdout.on('data', ...)` delivers unpredictable amounts of data.  You cannot assume that what you get on any given `data` event is exactly one perfect piece of JSON that is ready to parse.

If you're only getting one piece of JSON here from this whole child_process, then you need to accumulate all the data, combine it all together and in the `close` event parse and process all the combined data.

If you're getting multiple pieces of separate JSON (or could get multiple separate pieces), then you have to parse the stream yourself looking for some delimiter to know when one piece of JSON has finished and the next one has started so you can appropriately separate them and parse each one individually.  A `data` event will not necessarily deliver you a whole piece of JSON.  In fact, the larger the JSON is, the less likely you will get it all at once in one `data` event.  And, if you're rapidly sending multiple pieces of JSON from the child process, then you may even get more than one piece of JSON in a given `data` event.